# File permission error with newly uploaded image

Tags: php, file-upload, permissions

When I upload an image, I can view it in my browser, but when I try to view it from Windows Explorer, I get a file permission error.

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
$name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
if(strlen($name)) {
    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)) {
        if($size<(1024*1024)) {
            $actual_image_name = time().".".$ext;
            $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name)) {
                    echo "<img src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."' class='preview' width='306px'>";
            }
            else {
                echo "failed";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "Image file size max 1 MB";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Invalid file format..";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Please select image..!";
    exit;
}
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Change browsers? You don't indicate *which* browser seems to work in lieu of IE, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name)) {
    chmod($path.$actual_image_name, 0666); # set file to read-write for everybody
                    echo "<img src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."' class='preview' width='306px'>";
            }
```